# ContentTypRef and Schema.xml

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, list-definition, list-template

I am studying List Definition in sharepoint 2010.I have two files one schema.xml and another elements.xml

**elements.xml**

```
<ContentType ID="0x0101005CF0DB5B6075417a8664EFD23835C831"
           Name= "SCORM Content type"
           Group="Solutions" V2ListTemplateName="doclib" BaseType="0x0101"
           Description="This is the Content type for SCORM Library."
           Version="0">
    <FieldRefs>
<FieldRef Name="CourseName" ID="{B0884BE9-EE9D-4ae0-97E7-67AA0902A7FA}" />
</FieldRefs>
</ContentType>
   <ListTemplate
    Name="doclib"
    Type="1116"
    BaseType="1"
    OnQuickLaunch="FALSE"
    SecurityBits="11"
    Sequence="110"
    DisplayName="SCORM Library"
    Description="Library to store SCORM courses."
    Image="/_layouts/images/itdl.png"
    NewPage= "SL/Pages/XSLnew.aspx"
    Category="Libraries"
    DocumentTemplate="101"/>
```

**Schema.xml**

```
<ContentTypes>
  <ContentTypeRef ID="0x0101005CF0DB5B6075417a8664EFD23835C831">
    <Folder TargetName="Forms/Document" />
  </ContentTypeRef>
  <ContentTypeRef ID="0x0120" /> 
</ContentTypes>

 <Fields>    
 <Field ID="{B0884BE9-EE9D-4ae0-97E7-67AA0902A7FA}" Type="Text" Name="CourseName" DisplaceOnUpgrade="TRUE" DisplayName="Course Name" XName="TemplateUrl" Filterable="TRUE" Sortable="TRUE" Hidden="FALSE" FromBaseType="TRUE" PITarget="mso-infoPathSolution" PIAttribute="href" SourceID="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/v3" StaticName="CourseName"/>
 </Field>
  </Fields>
```

why we are adding ContentTypeRef? why its ID is 0x0120?why Type="1116" in ListTemplate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Separating each question.

Your Id of the `<ContentTypeRef ID="0x0120" />` specifies a reference to a content type to associate with the lis you are creating through the list definition. In particular, you are telling to associate Folder Content Type.

By the other hand in the Elements.xml, `type="1116"` is wrong because doesn't exist (take a look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splisttemplatetype%28v=office.14%29.aspx)

If you want to add a Document Library you should write `type="101"`

This is the list of tpyes for ListTemplate Element

> GenericList   Custom list. Value = 100.
>
> DocumentLibrary   Document library. Value = 101.
>
> Survey    Survey. Value = 102.
>
> Links Links. Value = 103.
>
> Announcements Announcements. Value = 104.
>
> Contacts  Contacts. Value = 105.
>
> Events    Calendar. Value = 106.
>
> Tasks Tasks. Value = 107.
>
> DiscussionBoard   Discussion board. Value = 108.
>
> PictureLibrary    Picture library. Value = 109.
>
> DataSources   Data sources for a site. Value = 110.
>
> WebTemplateCatalog    Site template gallery. Value = 111.
>
> UserInformation   User Information. Value = 112.
>
> WebPartCatalog    Web Part gallery. Value = 113.
>
> ListTemplateCatalog   List Template gallery. Value = 114.
>
> XMLForm   XML Form library. Value = 115.
>
> MasterPageCatalog Master Page gallery. Value = 116.
>
> NoCodeWorkflows   No Code Workflows. Value = 117.
>
> WorkflowProcess   Custom Workflow Process. Value = 118.
>
> WebPageLibrary    Wiki Page Library. Value = 119.
>
> CustomGrid    Custom grid for a list. Value = 120.
>
> SolutionCatalog   Solutions. Value = 121
>
> NoCodePublic  No Code Public Workflow. Value = 122
>
> ThemeCatalog  Themes. Value = 123
>
> DataConnectionLibrary Data connection library for sharing information
>   about external data  connections. Value = 130.
>
> WorkflowHistory   Workflow History. Value = 140.
>
> GanttTasks    Project Tasks. Value = 150.
>
> Meetings  Meeting Series (Meeting). Value = 200.
>
> Agenda    Agenda (Meeting). Value = 201.
>
> MeetingUser   Attendees (Meeting). Value = 202.
>
> Decision  Decisions (Meeting). Value = 204.
>
> MeetingObjective  Objectives (Meeting). Value = 207.
>
> TextBox   Text Box (Meeting). Value = 210.
>
> ThingsToBring Things To Bring (Meeting). Value = 211.
>
> HomePageLibrary   Workspace Pages (Meeting). Value = 212.
>
> Posts Posts (Blog). Value = 301.
>
> Comments  Comments (Blog). Value = 302.
>
> Categories    Categories (Blog). Value = 303.
>
> Facility  Facility. Value = 402
>
> Whereabouts   Whereabouts. Value = 403
>
> CallTrack Call Track. Value = 404
>
> Circulation   Circulation. Value = 405
>
> Timecard  Timecard. Value = 420
>
> Holidays  Holidays. Value = 421
>
> IMEDic    IME (Input Method Editor) Dictionary. Value = 499
>
> ExternalList  External. Value = 600
>
> IssueTracking Issue tracking. Value = 1100.
>
> AdminTasks    Administrator Tasks. Value = 1200.
>
> HealthRules   Health Rules. Value = 1220
>
> HealthReports Health Reports. Value = 1221

Comment: for adding document type we have to add DocumentTemplate="101" in ListTemplate tag.From my limited knowledge 1116 is a new type of list definition we are creating.Is this correct?

Comment: Right. With this number (1116) you are creating a Custom List definition but not a document library. My recommendation is to begin from 10000

Comment: Method i followed is to create a custom list definition from document library list template.Is my thoughts right?

Comment: If you want the same behaviour that a Document Library you should modify your type by 101 instead of 1116 but your method is right

Comment: What is the difference between DocumentTemplate="101" and BaseType="1"?

Comment: There is no difference. Each attribute is used for different scopes. In fact DocumentTemplate is only used when BaseType="1" The base type represents the default schema, for lists created from the definition: 0 -- GenericList, 
1 -- DocumentLibrary, 
3 -- DiscussionBoard, 
4 -- Survey, 
5 -- Issue

Comment: The list would still be a Document Library even with a Type of 1116 because the Content Type inherits from 0x0101. However, in SharePoint 2010, certain web parts will only work correctly if you reuse the OOTB type numbers. If this were not the case, you would want to use a unique type (like 1116) in order to distinguish your list template from any others, including the OOTB list templates.

Comment: Rich you are right buy for example you won't have the option "New Document" but "New Item".